# Do these sentences make sense?

Tags: formality

Notwithstanding the argument, I would still consider you as a friend.

I was exhausted, notwithstanding I stayed up for another two hours.

Maybe too formal to use in everyday writing as a word for "in spite of"?

Comment: I don't think "notwithstanding" is used as in the first sentence very often.  I don't usually write "notwithstanding _something_" but rather just "notwithstanding..." because the _something_ is implies by a prior sentence.

Comment: The second one—maybe split it into two sentences.  "I was exhausted. Notwithstanding, I stayed up..."

Comment: With regards to your first comment, George; that's what I thought. I had been told it was "Grammatically incorrect" but I was seeking another opinion.

Comment: Yes, you need a semicolon or above in the second example: otherwise you've got the dreaded comma splice. I'd choose 'In spite of' in the first sentence (and drop the 'would') and '. Nevertheless, ...' in the second. 'Notwithstanding' _does_ sound dated / formal / po-faced ... Incidentally, the first sentence does not have an ungrammatical usage of 'notwithstanding'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Okay, the comma splice will be taken care of.

Comment: Just Googling "notwithstanding meaning" gets you (or at least me)  straight to the Google article showing the different (allowable) usages, with examples. The article _doesn't_ tell you that none of the usages is commonly used outside the legal register. Nor does it mention the even rarer* postpositional usage: "The evidence notwithstanding, the consensus is that the jury will not reach a verdict".

Comment: *See the [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+evidence+notwithstanding%2Cnotwithstanding+the+evidence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20evidence%20notwithstanding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnotwithstanding%20the%20evidence%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Proof reading questions are off-topic unless you indicate a point of concern.

Answer (score 1):

To figure out a pedantic answer to this question on your own (and a very good approximation to a good one), you only need to look at the etymology of *notwithstanding*: *not with[=against]standing*, i.e. *not resisting*. This method doesn't work for all expressions with an obvious etymology, but in this case it helps. But we also need to be aware that in the word *notwithstanding*, *withstanding* is used more in the sense of *preventing it* or *standing in the way*.

- Notwithstanding the argument, I would still consider you [as] a friend.

(Note: I suspect that the word *as* towards the end is misleading and that it's about considering the other person to be a friend, not about considering them for some honour or similar because they are a friend.)

- Not withstanding the argument, I would still consider you [as] a friend.

This just doesn't sound right. In reality the original sentence is fine, but that's because *notwithstanding* increasingly behaves like a normal adverb. But with the space it says that because or if I don't withstand (oppose, resist, prevent) the argument, I would still ... I think that's probably not meant, and therefore the following is still more correct, especially for the register in which one would be tempted to use the word in the first place:

- The argument notwithstanding, I would still consider you [as] a friend.
- The argument not withstanding, I would still consider you [as] a friend.

As, or if, the argument does not withstand (prevent it), I would still ... .

Now the other example:

- I was exhausted, notwithstanding I stayed up for another two hours.

I don't even know what this is supposed to mean. If I just replace *notwithstanding* by a blank and try to guess what word belongs there, I would bet it's *but* or maybe something more fancy but equivalent like *nevertheless*. But with *notwithstanding* it seems to actually say something else, to wit:

- I was exhausted, not withstanding (opposing, resisting, preventing it) I stayed up for another two hours.

Clearly *notwithstanding* is modifying the wrong clause here. Literally it means that (1) I was exhausted, and (2) I stayed up for another two hours and while doing so I did not withstand (oppose, resist, prevent) my exhaustion. This doesn't seem to make much sense. Here is are two possible corrections:

- My exhaustion not withstanding, I stayed up for another two hours.
- My being exhausted not withstanding, I stayed up for another two hours.

It's important to understand that *notwithstanding*, like *withstand*, refers to a noun (or something grammatically equivalent), and not typically to a clause.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is certainly grammatical, though it would probably be too formal for most situations.

I don't think the second is correct in any way. *Notwithstanding* requires an object, so you could grammatically say *notwithstanding which* or (if you changed the comma into a semicolon) *that notwithstanding/ notwithstanding that fact*; all three are formal to the point of archaism.  *Nevertheless* would be a much better word.